# Xilinx ap_axiu parameters

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'm using ap_axiu from ap_axi_sdata.h in Vivado HLS like I saw in some example to stream data throught the AXI DMA.

I'm defining my value like this:

```
typedef ap_axiu<32,4,5,5> AXI_VALUE;
```

However, and even though I can see the following correspondence:

```
32-->data
4  -->user
4  -->id
5  -->dest
```

I can't understand what the 4,4 and 5 are for. Can someone please explain me what's the difference between **ap_axiu<32,1,1,1>** and **ap_axiu<32,4,4,5>**?

Note: I think this is something that should be said on the header file ap_axi_sdata because it's somewhat important.

Comment: Found a solution [here](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/ap-axiu-parameters/td-p/635138).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in most simple cases, 
where you don't need to route the stream chunks,
you can safely use ap_axiu<32,1,1,1>
V-italiano